# How do I wait for parameters before loading data?

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I have an application that has two types of data to load (data A, data B). 
There are three variations where I want to display the data.

If parameter A -> load data A

if parameter B -> load data B

if no parameter -> load data A

I have two functions assessParameters() which calls executeQueryParams()

```
  accessParameters(): void {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
      const queryStrings: any = this.route.queryParamMap;
      this.executeQueryParams(queryStrings.source.value);
    });
  }

async executeQueryParams(queryStrings): Promise<any> {
    const queries = Object.entries(queryStrings);
    for (const q of queries) {
      switch (q[0]) {
        case 'vendors':
          this.vendorTerm = q[1];
          if ( this.vendorsLoaded == false ) this.loadVendorData();
          break;
        case 'search':
          this.searchTerm = q[1];
          console.log("in executeQueryParams() for search");
          this.loadSearchData(); 
          break;
      }
      this.parametersLoaded = true;
    }
    return;
  }
```

If I load accessParameters() in ngOnInit or in the Constructor, it appears to load twice.  Initially, responding as if there are no parameters, even if there is one, and then a 2nd time processing the parameters.

If I have parameters, everything works as expected.  However, if I do not have parameter, it doesn't load any data. IF, I put in any logic that loads data if no parameters are found, than it always loads that data, regardless whether there are parameters or not.

I would like to be able to NOT load accessParameter() until the system is ready to process the parameters. ngAfterViewInit() did not work.

Comment: Can you provide a working demo so we can see the problem? For example here https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: I created a sample project that shows what I mean. 

https://github.com/ChipClark/testParameters

if there are no parameters when the app loads - it should (and does) display 
"We are not waiting" 

However, if there is a parameter when the app loads - it should display
"We are waiting for x seconds"
"We are done waiting"

however, it displays: 
"We are waiting for undefined seconds"
"We are not waiting" 

If you look in the console log - you'll see a variety of logs that show the load process.